# Dealing With Connection Break in For Loop, Wrong Behaviour

Tags: python, function, for-loop, while-loop, tweepy

I have the following For Loop which grabs the followers ids for a series of users using `Tweepy`:

```
def download_followers(user, api):
    all_followers = []
    try:
        for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=user).pages():
            all_followers.extend(map(str, page))
        return all_followers
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        print('Could not access user {}. Skipping...'.format(user))
```

The function is called in the following way:

```
for username in lookup_users:
    user_followers = download_followers(username, main_api)
    if user_followers:

        new_followers = pd.DataFrame({
            "Handles": username,
            "Follower_ID": user_followers,
            "Start_Date": today})

        new_followers_df = new_followers_df.append(new_followers)


        print('Finished outputting: {} at {}'.format(username, datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

Depending on the amount of followers each `user` might have, `Twitter's API` might have to be called twice or three times to grab all the `user's followers`.

Accordingly, there is a rest of 15 minutes before another call is made to the api. This is dealt by adding the following parameter to `Tweepy`:

```
main_api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
```

The result is something like this:

```
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 895
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 895
Finished outputting: @barackobama at 2017/07/01 10:36:07
```

Whereby the `API` in this case reached its limit twice. Waiting 15 minutes each time before grabbing all of `@barackobama`'s followers.

However, sometimes the `for loop` fails. Printing out the message:

```
    'Could not access user @barackobama. Skipping...'
```

This is mainly due to either a connection problem, the twitter api not being sent the right request, or an account having a lot of followers and Tweepy's package not being able to deal with it accordingly.

To account for a possible connection failure I tried wrapping the api in a `While True` argument as in the following way:

```
 def download_followers(user, api):
    all_followers = []
    while True:

        try:

            for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=user).pages():

                all_followers.extend(map(str, page))

                return all_followers

        except tweepy.TweepError:
            print('Could not access user {}. Trying Again...'.format(user))
            continue
        break
```

However, by wrapping the function this way, the for loop is not working properly. `Iterating` over each `user` just once, not grabbing all its followers, and moving on to the next `user` in the `lookup_user list.

For example, `instead` of behaving the following way:

```
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 895
'Could not access user @barackobama. Trying again...'
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 895
Finished outputting: @barackobama at 2017/07/01 10:36:07
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 895
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 895
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 895
Finished outputting: @donaldtrump at 2017/07/01 10:36:07
```

It acts the following way:

```
Finished outputting: @barackobama at 2017/07/01 10:36:07
Finished outputting: @donaldtrump at 2017/07/01 10:36:07
Finished outputting: @georgebush at 2017/07/01 10:36:07
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 895
Finished outputting: @richardnixon at 2017/07/01 10:41:08
```

Hence iterating over each user **only once**.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statement is inside the `for` loop, so the program exits the `for` loop after the first iteration.